# How do I change an image on hover over in WPF behind code dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I change an image on hover over in WPF behind code dynamically
i read an image from db and read also a hover image how to write code for image source and hover source?

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are for example MouseEnter and MouseLeave events where you could attach handlers that modify the image.

Comment: add your code sample to help you better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilise `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events and change `Image.Source` in code behind but why not use `Triggers` to change `Image.Source` when `IsMouseOver` is `true`. Like that you won't have to handle state when mouse leaves your control as it will simply re evaluate your style and revert to previous image source.
Trigger example:

```
<ContentControl>
   <ContentControl.Resources>
      <BitmapImage UriSource="ad.png" x:Key="ImgBtnLightbulbOff"/>
      <BitmapImage UriSource="ae.png" x:Key="ImgBtnLightbulbOn"/>
   </ContentControl.Resources>
   <ContentControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
         <Image Source="{StaticResource ImgBtnLightbulbOff}" x:Name="PART_Image"/>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ImgBtnLightbulbOn}"/>
            </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

`Image` must wrapped in some other control as `IsMouseOver` trigger is not changing `Source` on `Image` alone. I use `Resource` images but they can be taken from any place, for example data bound. 
But if you still need to do it in code behind here's an example:
XAML

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource ImgBtnLightbulbOff}" 
   MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" 
   MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave"/>
```

Code:

```
private void Image_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   var img = sender as Image;
   img.Source = (ImageSource)img.FindResource("ImgBtnLightbulbOff");
}

private void Image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   var img = sender as Image;
   img.Source = (ImageSource)img.FindResource("ImgBtnLightbulbOn");
}
```

Comment: I guess OP is asking for a code sample (not XAML) of such a Trigger. You may add that to your answer...

Comment: Done. Included both examples